# Why does the selenium not able to find an element using xpath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, whatsapp

I want to send some messages to multiple numbers in WhatsApp with the help of selenium. But, it works for the first number and does not work for the second number (don't know why this surprising behavior).

The following is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import socket
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/davidrm/Documents/pythonTutorials/WhatsAppMsg/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
sleep(10)


def element_presence(by, xpath, time):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(element_present)


# name = input('Enter the name of the user or group:')
msg = 'Hi!'
number_list = [7502878908, 8918786241,7502878908,7384942479]

input('Enter anything after scanning the QR Code.')


def get_phone(number):
    import re
    phone = ['+91'] + re.findall('.'*5, str(number))
    phone = " ".join(phone)
    return str(phone)


for number in number_list:
    number = int(number)
    contact = get_phone(number)
    element_presence(By.XPATH,f'//span[@title="{contact}"]',20)
    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f'//span[@title="{contact}"]'))).click()
    # #Fill message box
    element_presence(By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]',20)
    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
    msg_box.send_keys(msg)
    sleep(3)
    msg_box.send_keys("Something else")
    # # Sending message
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button'))).click()
```

I did added `sleep` and `WebDriverWait` thinking that the webdriver may be searching the element before it appears on the DOM. But still fails. The error message i get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidrm/Documents/pythonTutorials/WhatsAppMsg/toask.py", line 42, in <module>
    element_presence(By.XPATH,f'//span[@title="{contact}"]',20)
  File "/Users/davidrm/Documents/pythonTutorials/WhatsAppMsg/toask.py", line 18, in element_presence
    WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(element_present)
  File "/Users/davidrm/Documents/pythonTutorials/python3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Note: I didn't save any contacts and hence the name is in the span with the title as "+91 ***** *****".

[image: example]

Comment: Please try with the below line `element_presence(By.XPATH,f'//span[@title="%s"]%(contact)',20)`

Comment: Is it different than using format string??